# Find first two terms of sequence where the relationship of the first three terms is known

Tags: sequences-and-series

The sequence $u_n$ is defined by:

$u_{n+2}=2*u_{n+1}+2*u_n$ for $n\geq2$ with given $u_0$ and $u_1$

$u_0$ = 3

$u_1$ = 3

My goal is to find $u_2$ and $u_3$ but I'm struggling to see how I can go about this:

- Am I right to assume that $u_0$ and $u_1$ are irrelevant to finding $u_2$ and $u_3$?
- What steps can I take to get to $u_2$ and $u_3$?

Comment: Perhaps the problem intends for $n+2\geq 2$, not $n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note**: I think there is a mistake, and that should be $n\geq 0$, not $n\geq 2$.

---

No, you are not right in assuming that, you *need* them! The whole point of the formula 
$$ u_{n+2} = 2u_{n+1}+2u_n$$
is that it relates every term in the sequence to the previous two. Make sure you understand what this formula is saying.

Indeed, since it holds for $n\geq 0$, then put $n=0$ to get
$$ u_{2}=2u_1+2u_0.$$

This allows you to find $u_2$, and you can then find $u_3$ by a similar method.

Comment: Thank you. I solved the problem. with $n \geq 0$ the formulation of the problem becomes very clear.